# Datapath not displaying the correct path from treeview

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

```
**<components>
    <part>
        <manufacturer>asus</manufacturer>
        <model>A3-B</model>
    </part>
    <part>
        <manufacturer>intel</manufacturer>
        <model>V5-F</model>
    </part>
</components>**
```

This is the xml for which I created a treeview. I'm accessing the value through treeview.selectednode.datapath. The problem is that, everytime only the details of the first part gets displayed even if i click on the second part. How do i solve this problem?

Edit:
This is the c-sharp code:

```
protected void btnSelectFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          LoadXMLTree("~/first.xml");  
    }

private void LoadXMLTree(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            xmlDataSource.DataFile = fileName;
            xmlDataSource.EnableCaching = false;
            xmlTreeView.DataSourceID = "xmlDataSource";
            xmlTreeView.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Exception: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }

protected void xmlTreeView_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("~/first.xml");
        XmlNode node = 
                    doc.SelectSingleNode(xmlTreeView.SelectedNode.DataPath);
        txtEditXML.Text = node.InnerXml;
        Session["CurrentEditXpath"] = xmlTreeView.SelectedNode.DataPath;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a code snippet or something.

Comment: @LarsTech i have added the c# code. please take a look at it.

Comment: Better document what control you are using since that doesn't look like a standard TreeView control to me.  Also, WinForms?  ASP.Net?

Comment: @LarsTech it's not winforms. It is asp.net. And I don't know what control this is but it works for other cases. In case there's a better way that could solve the problem, please provide it.